# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - Error from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

Error Message:

> Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

React component:

```js
const checkBox = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={props.name} className='form-label'>
        {props.title}
      </label>
      <div className='checkbox-group'>
        {
          props.options.map(option => {
            return (
              <label key={option}>
                <input
                  className='form-checkbox'
                  id={props.name}
                  name={props.name}
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                  value={option}
                  checked={props.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1}
                  type='checkbox'
                />{' '}
                {option}
              </label>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In my code is anything going wrong? If yes please let me know. Can someone help me out from this?

The error

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Is thrown when the map function in the comment list component is executed.

Comment: Sounds like `options` might not be passed in.

Comment: Can you show how you’re using `checkbox` and passing down props? If `props` is an object, set a breakpoint or console.log() what it’s set to?

Comment: i follwed below procedure please check

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/blizzerand/building-forms-using-react-everything-you-need-to-know-iz3eyoq4y#comments-iz3eyoq4y

Comment: See the example at the end of [`<Select/>`](https://www.codementor.io/blizzerand/building-forms-using-react-everything-you-need-to-know-iz3eyoq4y#select) demonstrating how props are passed. You're more likely to receive help here on Stack Overflow by providing enough information for another developer to reproduce the problem on their own.

Comment: so should i have to do the same for checkbox ?

Comment: Yes. The author starts by showing what components you need in the form, then goes on in detail building their render method, event handlers, and showing props to pass in. He didn't show this detail for props with `<Checkbox/>`, looks like that's an exercise for the audience. :)

Comment: i have update checkbox props

Comment: <CheckBox 
        title={"Skills"}
        name={"skills"}
        placeholder={"Select Skills"}
        selectedOptions={"disable"}
        value={this.state.newUser.skillOptions}
        handleChange={this.handleSkillsCheckBox}/>

Comment: still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your question to include this information? I'll update my answer as your sample has corrections for me.

Answer (score 1):

A question comment references a [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/blizzerand/building-forms-using-react-everything-you-need-to-know-iz3eyoq4y) showing how to build a form and its sub-components. A couple of the components include examples of how to pass `props`, but that's missing from `<Checkbox/>`.

To fill that gap, here's an example of how you might expect to use `<Checkbox/>`. I didn't read the article in its entirety, so I'm hoping you can help correct any mistakes I've made here and it gets you started on your own development.

```
<Checkbox
       title={'Skills'}
       name={'skills'}
       options = {this.state.skills} <!-- array of skills or empty array -->
       selectedOptions = {this.state.newUser.skills} <!-- array of skills or empty array -->
       handleChange = {this.handleInput}
/>
```

Comment: The code sample above isn't intended as copy-paste but rather a starting point. What you actually pass to your `<Checkbox/>` component depends on what you're building around it.

Comment: Thank you..so much for your patience ... i got it

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple fallback like.

```
const checkBox = props => {
  const { options, name, titlem, selectedOptions, handleChange } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <label for={name} className="form-label">
        {title}
      </label>
      <div className="checkbox-group">
        {(options || []).map(option => {
          return (
            <label key={option}>
              <input
                className="form-checkbox"
                id={name}
                name={name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={option}
                checked={selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1}
                type="checkbox"
              />{" "}
              {option}
            </label>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkBox = ({  options, name, title, selectedOptions, handleChange }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={name} className='form-label'>
            {title}
          </label>
          <div className='checkbox-group'>
            {
           options && options.map(option => {
                return (
                  <label key={option}>
                    <input
                      className='form-checkbox'
                      id={name}
                      name={name}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={option}
                      checked={selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1}
                      type='checkbox'
                    />{' '}
                    {option}
                  </label>
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: It is better to provide more details about code in your answer